# Class Names in contenteditable text divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
return (
      <div
        onMouseUp={() => {
          this.handleMouseUp();
          this.showMenu();
        }}
        className="sectionWrite"
        contentEditable="true"
      >
        <div>
          <br></br>
        </div>
        {menuSelect}
      </div>
    );
```

Here is how the div appears after text is typed into the content editable div. For each child div inside the class sectionWrite, I want to name it a class.

```
<div class="sectionWrite" contenteditable="true">
  <div>adfasdfasdf</div>
  <div>asdlkfjasdlkjf</div>
  <div>asdfkljasdlfkjasdlkfj</div>
  <div>asdfkjasdlkfjasdf</div>
  <div>aklsdjfaskldjfas</div>
  <div>dfklasjdflkajdsf</div>
  <div>lkasjdflkjasdf</div>
  <div><br></div>
</div>
```

[what I type inside the editable div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCv3U.png)

When a client types in the contentEditable div, a new div encloses whatever the user typed. Is there any way to assign a class name to the div the user typed? I want to display a menu under a highlighted text and I would need a specific dom element to do that.

Comment: Could you give more details about what issue you got? A block of code not help that much

Comment: Please show people the input where user is typing in, plus the div that renders the result